# Using lapply to make a plot with factors from a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, plot, lapply

I generated a data frame with two factors, an x-variable, and a y-variable:

```
set.seed(1)
abc.df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 1000), col2 = rep(1:4, 750),
                      col3 = rnorm(3000), col4 = rnorm(3000, 2))
names(abc.df) <- c("factor1", "factor2", "q", "value")
abc.df$factor1 <- as.factor(abc.df$factor1)
abc.df$factor2 <- as.factor(abc.df$factor2)
abc_list <- split(abc.df, abc.df$factor1)
```

I want to generate a three plots for each letter (a, b, and c) with the number factors distinguished by color, but it generated an error message:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
lapply(abc_list, function(x) {plot(abc_list[[x]]$q, abc_list[[x]]$value,
                                   col = factor2)})
Error in abc_list[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

How can I make the series of plots with the right syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use `lapply` to loop through a list, the argument passed to the function is the element of the list not the index, so you can not use `abc_list[[x]]` to subset instead, just use `x`, so for your case:

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
lapply(abc_list, function(x) {plot(x$q, x$value, col = x$factor2)})
```

[image]

There is another convenient way to get this kind of plot using `ggplot2` package with `facet_grid`, where you don't need to split your original data frame into lists but specify the `factor1` as a variable to layout your plots:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(abc.df, aes(x = q, y = value, col = factor2)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(.~factor1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to get the title of each plot in base and the regression lines for each numeric factor.  And yes, I could do that with ggplot2, but I've been told to do it in base graphics.